# Register user through http request - Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need to register an user from one rails (3.2) web app to another one that uses devise, through http request. For example, if an user registers in the first app I want to register him automatically in the other app. How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can send the registration information through API of external application.

[Creation of API](http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already solved my problem! It was pretty simple, actually. I created a new method on the app that uses devise to accept a http request, creating an user using the received parameters (name, email, etc.). On my first app, when a user registers I send an http request to the created method with the desired data and the user is created successfully!